# THREAD WARNING - phonegap

Tags: плагин, phonegap, cordova, уведомления

Добрый день!

Плагин срабатывает на ios эмуляторе после того как я опускаю верхнюю шторку устройства и пишет:

> THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '1153.449951' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

Вот код:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
function onDeviceReady() { } 
function alertDismissed() { showAuthorizationPage(); } 
function showAlert() { 
    navigator.notification.alert( 'Вам нужно авторизоваться!', alertDismissed, 'Ошибка!', 'Ok' ); 
    }
```

Такая же проблема с InAppbrowser. Прошу помочь.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Добавте код.

Comment: document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
      
        }
        function alertDismissed() {
            showAuthorizationPage();
        }
        function showAlert() {
            navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Вам нужно авторизоваться!', 
                    alertDismissed,        
                    'Ошибка!',          
                    'Ok'                
            );
        }

Comment: Пользуйтесь кнопкой "править",  добавляйте или изменяйте вопрос. Вы же автор вопроса.